# Pure CSS Slider W/ Image Change on Hover

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a client for whom I've created the site http://StudyUp.com. At the top of the page we've made a slider that uses pure CSS to swap between the images. Today, the client asked if we could have the images change on radio button hover, or start automatically sliding through.

As far as I'm aware, this just ain't possible without jQuery, which we've been trying to avoid. However, if you've got anything to add, I'm all ears and very appreciative! Figured I'd ask the hive mind before deciding it was futile. If you know a quick jQuery fix I'm open to it, as well.

HTML for Slider is:

```
<div id="slider">
        <ul class="slider">
<li>
<input type="radio" id="slide1" name="slide" checked>
<a href="#"><label for="slide1"></label></a>
<img src="/images/Slide1.png" />
</li>
<li>
<input type="radio" id="slide2" name="slide">
<a href="#"><label for="slide2"></label></a>
<img src="/images/Slide2.png" />
</li>
<li>
<input type="radio" id="slide3" name="slide">
<a href="#"><label for="slide3"></label></a>
<img src="/images/Slide3.png" />
</li>
<li>
<input type="radio" id="slide4" name="slide">
<a href="#"><label for="slide4"></label></a>
<img src="/images/Slide4.png" id="slide4img" />
</li>
</ul>
    </div>
```

This here's the CSS for the sonoffagun:

```
/*This here's the CSS for that there slider*/
#slider {
  bottom:2%;
  left: -4%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top:65px;
  z-index: 15;
}
.slider. {
-webkit-transition: 0.15s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: 0.15s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: 0.15s ease-in-out;
transition: 0.15s ease-in-out;
height:580;
width: 1020px;
}
.slider li {
    -webkit-transition: 0.15s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: 0.15s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: 0.15s ease-in-out;
transition: 0.15s ease-in-out;
list-style: none; 
position:absolute;
}
.slider img {
    -webkit-transition: 0.15s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: 0.15s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: 0.15s ease-in-out;
transition: 0.15s ease-in-out;
  margin: 0 auto;
height:580;
width:1020px;
vertical-align: top;
}

.slider input {
display: none;
}
.slider label {
background-color:#69d2e7;
bottom: 8px;
cursor: pointer;
display: block;
height: 20px;
position:absolute; 
width: 20px; 
border-radius: 10px;
z-index: 10; 

-webkit-transition: background-color 0.15s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: background-color 0.15s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: background-color 0.15s ease-in-out;
transition: background-color 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
.slider li a:hover label {
  background-color: #297cab;
}

.slider li a:hover label:after  {
  background-color: #297cab;
}


.slider li:nth-child(1) label {
margin-bottom: 1.1%;
left: 40%;
} 
.slider li:nth-child(2) label { 
margin-bottom: 1%;
left: 45%;
}
.slider li:nth-child(3) label {
margin-bottom: 1%;
left: 50%;
}
.slider li:nth-child(4) label {
margin-bottom: 1%;
left: 55%; 
}
.slider img {
opacity: 0; 
visibility: hidden;
}

.slider li input:checked ~ img {
opacity: 1; 
visibility: visible; 
z-index: 10; 
}
```

Comment: i know this doesn't help with your problem, but you really should consider putting your `transition` elements into a class rather than retyping the code three times.

Comment: It is possible without JavaScript. For changing on hover, you just need to make use of the `:hover` pseudo-class and for changing automatically you can use keyframe animations.

Comment: Agreed :) This is an older project, and one with some sloppy code. Live and learn!

Comment: Right... but keyframe animations make the process much more complex. I believe that you shouldn't avoid jQuery, since almost 99% of internet devices have JavaScript support.

Comment: You are correct! We've tried using the :hover psuedo-class already, and experienced some issues. Keyframes would work, but either way, I think @Santz solution below is the way to go. Thanks either way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this. It's Chris Coyer's solution. Very very simple and lightweight.

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/simple-auto-playing-slideshow/

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful, and will do nicely for the gig. Thanks again for the link!

Comment: To update, this tutorial did the trick entirely! Situation has been resolved, and I couldn't be happier. Thanks again, Santz, and others!

Answer (score 0):

You can attain a mouseover image transition by changing :checked event to :hover in your su-home.css, line no: 202

```
.slider li input:hover ~ img {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: You are correct! However, the issue with this is that the hover image doesn't remain in place afterward.